# Java: API to get a certificate issuer chain given a leaf certificate?

Tags: java, security, certificate

Does a Java security API exists which, given an arbitrary certificate and a list of certificates (or keystore), retrieve the chain of issuers for that certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder`

Comment: How do you use it to accomplish what OP asked?

Comment: @ClayFowler You lookup the Javadoc.